# Finding an explicit inverse on a neighborhood for a function $\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse

I have the continuously differentiable function $f(x,y)=(x^3y,xy)$. Its Jacobian is
$$\begin{pmatrix}3x^2y&x^3\\y&x\end{pmatrix}.$$
At $(1,1)$, the Jacobian is non-zero, so by the inverse function theorem, there is an neighborhood of $(1,1)$ in which $f$ has a continuously differentiable inverse. I would like to find the inverse of $f$ in this neighborhood.

If I invert the Jacobian, I get
$$\frac{1}{2x^3y}\begin{pmatrix}x&-x^3\\-y&3x^2y\end{pmatrix}.$$
However, I am not sure what function would has such a Jacobian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just invert directly.

It is easy to see that if $x=0$ or $y=0$ then the function is not invertible.

If $(x,y) \neq 0$, then let $a=x^3y,b=xy$. Then dividing (or cubing and dividing) gives $x^2 = \frac{a}{b}$, $y^2 = \frac{b^3}{a}$.

Hence there are four possible solutions $x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$, $y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{b^3}{a}}$. The neighborhood you are in will dictate which solution to use.

**Note**: I forgot to mention that $a$ and $b$ always have the same sign (since $x, x^3$ have the same sign), so the square root is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a,b) = f(x,y) = (x^3y,xy)$, since $(x,y)$ is near $(1,1)$, $a=x^3y\neq 0$ and $b=xy\neq 0$. Thus $$x = \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\ \text{and}\ \ y = \sqrt{\frac{b^3}{a}},$$where the positive roots are to be taken as is customary.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(1,1)=(1,1)$,by inverse function theorem,there exist $g(x,y)$ such that $g(f(x,y))=(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)$ in a neighborhood of $(1,1)$ (call it $U$) and $g'(a,b)=(f'(g(a,b)))^{-1}$ for all $(a,b)$ in $f(U)$. As you have shown, $f'(x,y)^{-1}=\frac{1}{2x^3y}\begin{pmatrix}x&-x^3\\-y&3x^2y\end{pmatrix}$, hence $g'(a,b)=\frac{1}{2x^3y}\begin{pmatrix}x&-x^3\\-y&3x^2y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2\sqrt ab}&\frac{-\sqrt a}{2b\sqrt b}\\\frac{-b\sqrt b}{2a\sqrt a}&\frac{3\sqrt b}{2\sqrt a}\end{pmatrix}$, so $g(a,b)=(\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}+c_1,\frac{b\sqrt b}{\sqrt a}+c_2)$, where $c_1,c_2$ are constant. since $g(f(1,1))=g(1,1)=(1,1)$, $c_1=c_2=0$, hence $g(a,b)=(\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b},\frac{b\sqrt b}{\sqrt a})$.

Comment: This answer contains nothing new.